# Script/Terminal to move files of similar name to unified folder

Tags: terminal, script, naming

Wonder if anyone can help..bit of a noob and I've found partial answers online but nothing specific.

**I'm using OSX 10.11**

I have a folder with a LOT of older artwork files and would like to use Terminal or a script to place files of a similar or same name into a folder together with the same name.

EG:
**FOLDER: ALL**
Monster1
Cat colours
Monster Prelims
Girl coloured
Girl2
Monster 2
Cat sketch
Monster with colours
Cat finalised
Monster final

*Would end up like this:*

**FOLDER: MONSTER**
Monster1
Monster 2
Monster Prelims
Monster final
Monster with colours

**FOLDER: GIRL**
Girl coloured
Girl2

**FOLDER:CAT**
Cat sketch
Cat finalised
Cat colours

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it like this:
`mkdir Monster`
`mv Monster* Monster/` (move everything that starts with "Monster" into Monster/)
Then repeat the same commands with different files/folders

Comment: That certainly works but there are literally thousands of files with lots of different names. My hope was the script could search names it deems have similar names and generate a folder based on that name.

Comment: You can always append the command, so if you have a file named 13M0nster you can use "mv *M*ster Monster/".

Answer (score 0):

If I had this problem I would first create a file with prefixes by doing `ls -1 | sort > prefixes`, edit the prefixes file and manually deleting the file names and replacing it with the proper prefixes.
Then I would use that one to do a move like ecstasy proposed for all prefixes.

So the prefixes file would first read

```
Cat colours
Cat finalised
Cat sketch
Cows
Girl coloured
Girl2
Monster 2
Monster Prelims
Monster final
Monster with colours
Monster1
```

And be saved containing

```
Cat
Girl
Monster
```

(I added a Cows line that is not to be put in a subfolder)
Then with the proper shell syntax this can be processed, for example in zsh with

```
for h in `cat prefixes`
do
  mkdir $h
  mv $h* $h
done
```

Hope this helps, Ruud

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think this method will still be too time-consuming. The folder in question probably has around 7k files in it.

What I really need is something that

• Checks all names of files in folder

• Identifies when several files have the same or similar name

e.g. it will select super-hero.jpeg super-hero5.psd AND super-girl.png

• It will then create a folder based upon this identified recurring name

• Moves the selected files to said folder

I’m assuming this may be impossible, but will keep trying.

Comment: the tricky part is the identification of similar names. This is why I suggested to do it manually, any algorithm will probably has its strong and weak points. I wish you success....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion. I think this method will still be too time-consuming. The folder in question probably has around 7k files in it.

What I really need is something that

• Checks all names of files in folder

• Identifies when several files have the same or similar name

e.g. it will select super-hero.jpeg super-hero5.psd AND super-girl.png

• It will then create a folder based upon this identified recurring name

• Moves the selected files to said folder

I’m assuming this may be impossible, but will keep trying.